# Why does my "INSERT INTO" Statement not work?

Tags: sql, derby

I am working with Apache derbyDB (db2) and SQL Workbench as environment. I have 10k records of data and I want to create a star schema with dimension tables and a fact table.

```
dwh_price_paid_records = data table
dm_price_paid_records = data mart table (facts table)
dim_time =  data mart table (dimension)

DWH_PRICE_PAID_RECORDS.TRANSACTION_ID = VARCHAR(50)
DWH_PRICE_PAID_RECORDS.PRICE = INTEGER
DWH_PRICE_PAID_RECORDS.DATE_OF_TRANSFER = DATE
DIM_TIME.DATE_ID = Primary key of dim_time (autoincrement start with 1 increment by 1)
DM_PRICE_PAID_RECORDS.DATE_ID = Foreign key NOT NULL from DIM_TIME
```

In the Facts table (DM_PRICE_PAID_RECORDS) I only want to have the the primary key, the price (fact) and the ID, to have a relation to the dimension table but its not working.

```
INSERT INTO DM_PRICE_PAID_RECORDS (TRANSACTION_ID, PRICE, DATE_ID) VALUES (SELECT TRANSACTION_ID FROM DWH_PRICE_PAID_RECORDS, SELECT PRICE FROM DWH_PRICE_PAID_RECORDS, SELECT DATE_ID FROM DIM_TIME join DWH_PRICE_PAID_RECORDS on DIM_TIME.DATE = DWH_PRICE_PAID_RECORDS.DATE_OF_TRANSFER WHERE DIM_TIME.DATE = 
DWH_PRICE_PAID_RECORDS.DATE_OF_TRANSFER);
```

I wouldve expected this as an outcome:

TRANSACTION_ID | PRICE | DATE_ID

1|  2324 |    423

2              |  52315 |    234

But I get an error in german language saying something like:
"VALUES-clause must have atleast one element. Emtpy elements are not allowed"

"VALUES-Klausel muss mindestens ein Element enthalten. Leere Elemente sind nicht zulässig."

Thank you so much!
Flippi

Comment: As Gordon says, it's partially your syntax. There can be only one select clause in there and it should result in the rows you want to put into your table - matching the number of columns needed.

Comment: The syntax for a `VALUES` clause is `(<column>[, per next column])[, per next row]`.  Your statement is trying to put multiple rows into a single-row element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `INSERT . . . SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO DM_PRICE_PAID_RECORDS (TRANSACTION_ID, PRICE, DATE_ID)
    SELECT ppr.TRANSACTION_ID, ppr.PRICE, t.DATE_ID
    FROM DWH_PRICE_PAID_RECORDS ppr JOIN
        DIM_TIME t 
        ON t.DATE = ppr.DATE_OF_TRANSFER ;
```

Comment: I love you! thank you so much :) I spent so many hours on this you wouldnt believe me..